# Match exactly 11 occurences of the same digit in a group

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match exactly 11 occurences of the same digit in a group, like:

- 11111111111
- 55555555555

But not:

- 11111000111
- 55552225555

What I've tried so far can get 11 occurences of digits:

```
/([0-9]){11}/g
/\d{11}/g
```

But it will match any 11 digits.

I've managed to do this:

```
/(0{11}|1{11}|2{11}|3{11}|4{11}|5{11}|6{11}|7{11}|8{11}|9{11})/g
```

Is there any other easier way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/(\d)\1{10}/
```

This matches the first digit and uses a reference to that digit `\1` to match it ten more times.  Note that this will also match if the digit repeats 12 or more times, and if other digits start the string, but this seems to be desired.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm and it's really easy to understand.

Answer (score 3):

You should use **backreference**: `((\d)\2{10})`

The `\2` matches "the same thing as was the 2nd caputing group (parentheses)".

https://regex101.com/r/QESWrJ/1

Comment: It worked too, thanks. A question about this `\2`. Is it referencing the group inside the group?

Comment: The 1st group is the outer parentheses (whole match) and the 2nd is the inner `(\d)`. The order is determined from the pattern string left-to-right.